# SQLite Table not being created

Tags: java, android

I have a database created in android studio to save data to . The table is not being created in the database . The error I'm getting is :

```
03-04 00:55:45.783 25787-25787/com/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: TableName
03-04 00:55:45.783 25787-25787/com.E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting
```

My code for creating the table is :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("DB.ad",null);
    Log.v(TAG, "*TABLE ");
    // create TableName table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TableName_TABLE);
    this.checkDataBase();
}
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_FULL_PATH, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
       checkDB.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database doesn't exist yet.
    }
    return checkDB != null;

}
```

I was wondering if anyone can tell me why I am getting this error?

```
String CREATE_TableName_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE TableNames( " +
                                                "Id INT( 30 ) PRIMARY KEY     AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                                "TagNo TEXT, " +
                                                "Description TEXT, " +
                                                "WeeksGone INTEGER( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 );";
```

Comment: are u updating your database version?

Comment: @JpCrow how do I do that ? I've never worked with databases in android before.

Comment: Can you post `CREATE_TableName_TABLE`?

Comment: I think the SQL statement you are using is the culprit.
It should be CREATE TABLE <tablename>

Comment: As a side note, you should use an `SQLiteOpenHelper`. It provides well-defined lifecycle methods for DB creation, upgrade, and downgrade.

Comment: @Hannah I updated my answer after your update.

Comment: So... you create `TableNames`, but want to access `TableName`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to create your database. First your class should extends from    **SQLiteOpenHelper**

Then use super to SQLiteOpenHelper class with your db name and version,

```
 public YourClassName(Context context) {
    super(context, "YourDatabaseName", null, 1); // 1 is the version of the database, after each change in your db you should ++.
}
```

Then create your table:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    final String SQL_CREATE_BLABLA_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + "TableNameHere" + " (" +
            "_id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
           "name" + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_BLABLA_TABLE);
 }
```

And finally in case you need to upgrade your db version, because you make any change override the onUpgrade method, in order to create again the table.

```
  @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TableNameHere");
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
 }
```

For more information of how to implement SQLite please read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Please review the following types in order to create your table:

> 1.0 Storage Classes and Datatypes
>
> Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the database engine) has one of the following storage classes:
>
> NULL. The value is a NULL value.
>
> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
>
> REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
>
> TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
>
> BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

For more information of datatypes please see this [link](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

So your table should be create like this:

```
String CREATE_TableName_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE TableNames (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TagNo TEXT, 
Description TEXT, WeeksGone INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 );";
```